# Showing turn-by-turn directions during navigation, using Mapbox Optimized Trips

Tags: android, navigation, mapbox, directions, turn-by-turn

I'm using the Optimized Trips Mapbox's API, and I've got an issue that I couldn't solve for myself. Maybe i'm trying to achieve something a little greedy taking into account the API was released for about one week, I don't think I can lose anything asking.

Here's my current context:
I'm creating an optimized trip, based in 2-9 points located manually by the user. Everything OK until now, the route is perfectly created, but my real objective is to after that, launch another activity with the navigation API embedded, which's only function would be the navigation, showing below a little message with turn-by-turn navigation orders.
I am not finding the way to grab the retrieved route and starting my navigation in another activity with that previously settled route.

```
MapboxOptimizedTrips.Builder builder = new MapboxOptimizedTrips.Builder()
                .setAccessToken(Mapbox.getAccessToken())
                .setProfile(DirectionsCriteria.PROFILE_DRIVING)
                .setSource(DirectionsCriteria.SOURCE_FIRST)
                .setOverview(DirectionsCriteria.OVERVIEW_FULL);

        MapboxOptimizedTrips client = builder.setCoordinates(al).build();
```

How can I do to given that response, launch another activity with the navigation (driver's point of view) and giving turn-by-turn directions also?

Sorry if I'm bringing up any older question, the main reason is because I'm not really familiarized with Mapbox Navigation, and I'm not being capable of solving it by myself.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When starting a new navigation session, you should be able to pass in a DirectionsRoute object (which the APIs response provides). If you run into any troubles, open a GitHub issue so we can look further into it. This is an interesting use case and I might have overlooked it.